# How to access the particular item in tuple inside nested list in python

Tags: python

I have a list like the one below.

```
List = [[('1', 'AR123 <br/> ')], [('8', 'AR987 <br/> SR149728 <br/> Fix for BOM')], []]
```

Needed output:

```
AR123
AR987
SR149728
Fix for BOM
```

Can you help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking for code that works in this specific case, or that works in some more general situation (such as printing out all contained strings that contain at least one alphabetic character, or that have length greater than one, or...)?

Comment: In general, I want the second item should be printed

Answer (score 1):

```
print list[0][1], list[1][1]
```

If I read this correctly, you want the second element of each sub-list.  A more generalized version would be

```
for item in list:
    print item[1],

print
```

Comment: `list[0][1]` raises `IndexError: list index out of range` in OP,  nested 3 times `[[(,  )], ]`.

Comment: Whoops!  Right you are.  I missed the extra bracket set.  Noting the OP's comment, that's actually a typo: wanted the second element of each item.  In this case, my answer is correct for the *intended* problem.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
List = [[('1', 'AR123 <br/> ')], [('8', 'AR987 <br/> SR149728 <br/> Fix for BOM')], []]


str_list = [t[1].split('<br/>') for sublist in List for t in sublist]
# [['AR123 ', ' '], ['AR987 ', ' SR149728 ', ' Fix for BOM']]

result = [s.strip() for sublist in str_list for s in sublist if s.strip()]
# ['AR123', 'AR987', 'SR149728', 'Fix for BOM']

print('\n'.join(result))
# Output
AR123
AR987
SR149728
Fix for BOM
```

---

Previous answer,

```
lists = [[('1', 'AR123 ')], [('8', 'AR987 SR149728 Fix for BOM')], []]

result = [t[1] for sublist in lists for t in sublist]

print(result)
# Output
['AR123 ', 'AR987 SR149728 Fix for BOM']
```

Answer (score 0):

The tuples are nested in single-item list

```
List = [[('1', 'AR123 ')], [('8', 'AR987 SR149728 Fix for BOM')], []]

print(List[1][0][1])
```

Without extra list-item

```
List = [('1', 'AR123 '), ('8', 'AR987 SR149728 Fix for BOM'), None]

print(List[1][1])
```

Both return:

AR987 SR149728 Fix for BOM